# R pass value of column as value for selecting column from array

Tags: r

I am trying to pass the value of an existing R attribute (column) as the value needed for identifying the particular column in an array I want to select.  I previously wrote an For loop with an IF statement but it is running really slow.

Each person will have a group membership (1, 2, or 3).  I have the probability of their group membership in data$prob1, data$prob2, and data$prob3.

I want to pass the value of data$Group as follows:

data$ClstrAffinity  = data$Prob[ , data$Group]

but it does not work.  Any ideas?

The slow running code is below.

Thank you.

```
data$ProbOne = data$Prob[ , 1]
data$ProbTwo = data$Prob[ ,2]
data$ProbThree = data$Prob[ ,3]
data$GroupMembershipNumeric = as.numeric(data$Group)

data[data$Group == 1]

for (a in c(1:nrow(data))) {
  groupMembership = data$GroupMembershipNumeric[a]
  if (groupMembership == 1) {
    data$ClstrAffinity[a] = data$ProbOne[a]
  }
  if (groupMembership == 2) {
    data$ClstrAffinity[a] = data$ProbTwo[a]
  }
  if (groupMembership == 3) {
    data$ClstrAffinity[a] = data$ProbThree[a]
  }
  print(groupMembership)
  groupMembership = NULL
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example? We can only guess without data.

Comment: You've mixed some names, I think. `ClstrAffinity` is the same as `ProbFinal`?

Comment: Hi Aaron, you are correct.  I typed that incorrectly and will edit the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matrix indexing is what you need.  I'll generate some sample data

```
set.seed(5)
Prob <- matrix(sample(0:10, 15, replace=TRUE)/10, ncol=3)
Group <- sample(1:3,5,replace=TRUE)
```

Then your desired result is just

```
ProbFinal <- Prob[cbind(1:5,Group)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `which`:

```
data$ProbFinal = "NA"

data$ProbOne = data$Prob[ ,1]
data$ProbTwo = data$Prob[ ,2]
data$ProbThree = data$Prob[ ,3]

data$ProbFinal[which(data$Group == 1)] = data$ProbOne[which(data$Group  == 1)]
data$ProbFinal[which(data$Group == 2)] = data$ProbTwo[which(data$Group == 2)]
data$ProbFinal[which(data$Group == 3)] = data$ProbThree[which(data$Group == 3)]
```